# How to create a video from map trajectory

Tags: android, google-maps, video-capture

I have a mobile app that track user's location. I want to create a video from tracked points on map. something like [relive.cc](https://relive.cc) 
can anybody suggest a solution, server-side or client-side doesn't matter